# Titanium.UI.ScrollableView doesn't show children when scrolling fast

Tags: javascript, ios, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

In my `Titanium IOS app` I have a `ScrollableView` populated with several `WebViews`.
When scrolling slowly between views everything works fine and I'm able to see the views as they slide back and forth.

However, when trying to scroll fast (by flicking the screen) the `ScrollableView` gets black almost immediately, giving me no feedback of whether I'm scrolling or not. Even though the ScrollableView goes black it still scrolls though.

Maybe flicking isn't supported? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I believe this is related to caching of views **[cacheSize](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ScrollableView-property-cacheSize)**

Comment: Setting an arbitrary cacheSize does help some, but only If I've already visited the views I'm scrolling over.
I'f I scroll over views I've not "visited" before the black behavior occurs.

Comment: Can you please share your code.